# Why does it needed to define data-type's size in oracle (or any other DB)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Let's say for example I am creating a table with some columns like:

```
COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE            NULLABLE   and .......
===========   =========            ========   ============================
NAME          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)   No
GENDER        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)     No
```

While creating the table I need to define the data size for the columns `NAME (100 BYTE)` and `GENDER (1 BYTE)`.
Can someone explain what exactly the purpose of this?

For the `NAME` column I am allocating `100 BYTE`. But some times the name value may not occupy `100 BYTE`. So it wastes some space, right? Why can't the DB itself manages it automatically?

Comment: `varchar` is a variable length data type. There is no spaces wasted when storing just 1 character in a `varchar(100)` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, but may I know the purpose of defining that variable length?

Comment: It's a business constraint. You state that you do not want to store values longer then that (btw. in Postgres you are not _required_ to specify a maximum length). You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8295131/330315 and the Oracle Concepts guide: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#GUID-5D05C023-C309-46DA-A7EC-2BED1CA512A7

Answer (score 2):

The varchar2 parameter defines the maximum amount of characters allowed to store in the column. This has very little to do with the actual storage space allocated per row. The database can use as little as it wants as long as the actual stored value fits.

However the database normally adds some margin/extra space to each block when storing a row in order to allow for growth when values change. How much this uses depends on the PCTFREE table setting.

Even if the extra space left is not enough, the value can still be stored. The database will just have to push the other data within the same storage box (called a block). If the box however becomes full, another block has to be allocated and data split over these blocks. This leads to fragmentation that has negative effects on performance.

Coming back to the original storage limitation it states the maximum storage limit for each row in this column. It may not be exceed this amount. And there is a limitation to how large this limit may be set. For varchar2 it is 4K on most Oracle versions. Probably because the default block size used to be 4K on most platforms.