# Should we validate max length on string fields?

Tags: postgresql

We have a validation in our application limiting user first and last name length to 255 characters. Is there any technical reason we *ought* to be doing this? I'm wondering if there is maybe any security concern or risk we put ourselves at by not limiting the length of strings. We're using Postgres  `text` columns.

Comment: If this is a business constraint, then yes you should reflect that in a database constraint as well. If you are indexing the columns you probably should limit the length as well. Note that there is no optimization whatsoever for column defined as `varchar(255)` over a column defined as `varchar(260)` or `varchar(301)` - that `255` is a left-over "magic number" that does have any performance impact

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295131

Answer (score 1):

`Text` = variable unlimited length.. If you put limiter why don't use `varchar(255)`?

For security concern and performance put limiter are good. If your database file heavy and if someone spams to your `text`, the data type exceeds 8 KB.. That will put heavy in your db and for worst scenario it can `Break Down`..

*EDIT* :

As [`Documentation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) says:

> If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use
>   text or character varying without a length specifier, rather than
>   making up an arbitrary length limit.

Back to your original question "*Should we validate max length on string fields*"?

When see documentation said.. It would be better you make as `Varchar(255)` rather than `Varchar` without length specifier and do limiter in application side

And for performance:

> Long strings are compressed by the system automatically, so the
>   physical requirement on disk might be less. Very long values are also
>   stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid
>   access to shorter column values.

I will say great for Postgresql :)

Comment: The PostgreSQL docs actually suggest that `text` is no less performant, though, if you need something variable length, and may be better since they don't need to check the length before storing a value. See the Tip here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-character.html

Comment: @lobati yes.. I am already read that.. about performance which is great `postgresql`.. And said `If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use text or character varying without a length specifier, rather than making up an arbitrary length limit.`..

Comment: I can't see how you could "break down" the database by supplying long strings.

Comment: Yes.. I want to remove that @a_horse_with_no_name but if i remove the first argument i show i think that's not good.. That's just my speculation.. If i am wrong you can dv me.. :)