# Are there any benefits of havin CharField defined smaller than little larger?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's assume that in some particular case I know that I will need `CharField` for single words. I wonder does the length of `CharField` influences the performance of the query, or the size of DB when it's defined as bigger.

In this case, I assume that all data fit the size of `CharField` because - let's assume - that in every row in the column each cell has a word with length 3. For example:

[image]

What changes when I define the length of CharField to 3, or 250?

**I'm aware that there are (many) other reasons to define `CharFiled` in some way (define a particular allowed range)**, but are there any reasons to try to make the available range smaller for the sake of performance or the size of `DB`? Is it worth considering and if so, when?

Would it be the same for **SQLite** and **PostgreSQL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295131/best-practices-for-sql-varchar-column-length/8295254#8295254) it does not seem that there are any size on disk benefits or optimisations on performance for limiting the max length.